# How do I add a topic to Freebase?

Tags: contributing-data

I know this question seems relatively simple but not a single guide I've seen on the topic of how I add a topic/entity to Freebase references the current structure of the site. I've clicked through virtually every link on the page hunting for something that would indicate that it would let you add a new entity and I just don't get why I can't find it. I'm not sure why it's such a complicated process but I would appreciate it if someone could explain what I'm missing. Specifically, I would like to know how I can add a company entity to the site.

Answer (score 2):

Copied directly from Freebase ([source](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Creating_a_new_topic))...

> Many times when you think you need to Create a New Topic, you probably will NOT need to.
>
> **IF YOU'RE SURE YOU NEED TO CREATE A NEW [Topic](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Topic) in Freebase:**
>
> Think about what sort of thing your topic is. For instance, is it a Person, Film, or Skyscraper.
>
> On Freebase.com, navigate to that [Type](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Type) (the [Search](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Search) interface at the top of each page is an easy way to do this)
>
> When you are on the type page, click "Add more topics" in the upper right of the page
>
> Enter the name of your new topic
>
> Once it is added, you can click through to it and then [edit it](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Editing_topics) to add more information.
>
> New topics usually appear in a Search within a minute or so, but this can be longer if the system is under high load.
>
> SEE ALSO: [FAQs about Topics](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_suggest#FAQs)

Comment: The problem is that there is no "Add more topics" in the upper right of the page as far I can see. See here - http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ac2u2y312

Comment: topics can only be added at certain pages. try here, for example: https://www.freebase.com/organization/organization?schema=   and direct link   https://www.freebase.com/organization/organization?create=

Comment: So it looks like you can only add to pages marked as "type" and not "topic". I'm not sure of the difference but I do know that the "privately-held company" entity is a topic so it doesn't appear you can add your own company. That doesn't seem right given the purpose of the site so it's possible I'm still missing something.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure the distinction either.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the initial version of OpenRefine (freebase Gridworks) was designed to populate freebase. However I am not sure if this option is still supported now Google have took over freebase and is not supporting OpenRefine anymore.